# Using Invariance of Lorentz interval and constant speed of light to prove the Lorentz transformations

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

By the invariance of the Lorentz interval and the fact that the speed of light is the same in both frames we have
\begin{align*}
-c^2 dt^2 + dx^2 = -c^2 dt'^2 + dx'^2
\end{align*}
By considering the set of points with t = const we obtain
\begin{align*}
dx^2 = -c^2 dt'^2 + dx'^2
\end{align*}
By definition of the differential we have
\begin{align*}
dx &= \frac{\partial x}{\partial t'} dt' + \frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} dx'
\\ dx' &= \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} dx = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} dx
\\ dt &= \frac{\partial t}{\partial t'} dt' + \frac{\partial t}{\partial x'} dx'
\\ dt' &= \frac{\partial t'}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial t'}{\partial x} dx = \frac{\partial t'}{\partial x} dx
\end{align*}
Substituting the differentials we obtain
\begin{align*}
dx^2 = - c^2 \left( \frac{\partial t'}{\partial x} dx\right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} dx \right)^2
\\ dx^2 = - c^2 \left( \frac{\partial t'}{\partial x} \right)^2 dx^2 + \left( \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \right)^2 dx^2
\\ dx^2 + c^2 \left( \frac{\partial t'}{\partial x} \right)^2 dx^2 - \left( \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \right)^2 dx^2 = 0
\\ dx^2 \left(1 + c^2 \left( \frac{\partial t'}{\partial x} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \right)^2 \right)  = 0
\\ \left(1 + c^2 \left( \frac{\partial t'}{\partial x} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \right)^2 \right)  = 0
\end{align*}
Now considering the set of points with x = const we obtain
\begin{align*}
-c^2 dt^2 = -c^2 dt'^2 + dx'^2
\end{align*}
Now substituting the differentials we obtain
\begin{align*}
-c^2 dt^2 = -c^2 \left( \frac{\partial t'}{\partial t} dt\right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial x'}{\partial t} dt \right)^2
\\ -c^2 dt^2 = -c^2 \left( \frac{\partial t'}{\partial t}\right)^2 dt^2 + \left( \frac{\partial x'}{\partial t} \right)^2 dt^2
\\ -c^2 dt^2 + c^2 \left( \frac{\partial t'}{\partial t}\right)^2 dt^2 - \left( \frac{\partial x'}{\partial t} \right)^2 dt^2 = 0
\\ dt^2 \left(-c^2  + c^2 \left( \frac{\partial t'}{\partial t}\right)^2  - \left( \frac{\partial x'}{\partial t} \right)^2 \right) = 0
\\ \left(-c^2  + c^2 \left( \frac{\partial t'}{\partial t}\right)^2  - \left( \frac{\partial x'}{\partial t} \right)^2 \right) = 0
\end{align*}

Where do I go from here? If I want to obtain:

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
t' = \gamma \left( t - \frac{v}{c^2} x \right) \\
x' = \gamma \left( x - vt \right)
\end{cases}
 \qquad \text{ where } \gamma \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2}} \ge 1
\end{align*}